# Moment js and IOS

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to create an array of dates between two dates using Moment.js
The following works on my PC but not on my iphone or ipad ( device seizes).
If I change the stopDate to 2016-09-24 or less it works on my devices

```
 var arr=[];
  var startDate = moment("2016-06-01")
    var stopDate=moment("2016-09-29")   
    while (startDate.isBefore(stopDate)) {        
   arr.push( moment(startDate).format('YYYY-MM-DD') )      
    startDate = moment(startDate).add(1, 'days');

                           }           
        alert(arr)
```

Comment: You could try declaring the date format in the `moment()`. If iOS handles `Date` differently than PC which it probably does you could be getting errors. `var startDate = moment("2016-06-01", "YYYY-MM-DD")`. Also for incrementing the date, just do `startDate.add(1, 'days');` no need for `startDate = ...`

Comment: and you can just do `startDate.format('YYYY-MM-DD')` instead of `moment(startDate).format('YYYY-MM-DD')`. `startDate` is already a `moment`

Comment: I tried  var arr=[];
   var startDate = moment("2016-06-01","YYYY-MM-DD")
          var stopDate=moment("2016-09-29","YYYY-MM-DD")                     
    
  while (startDate.isBefore(stopDate)) {        
           arr.push(startDate.format('YYYY-MM-DD') )
       
  startDate.add(1, 'days');
                  } 
        
   alert(arr) but got the same problem

Answer (score 0):

This works for me. https://jsfiddle.net/stevenkaspar/mLwjdzey/

```
<script>
 var arr = [];
 var startDate = moment("2016-06-01");
 var stopDate = moment("2016-09-29");
 while (startDate.isBefore(stopDate)) {
   arr.push( startDate.format('YYYY-MM-DD') );
   startDate.add(1, 'days');
 }
 console.log(arr);
</script>
```

Comment: Thanks for that. The jsfiddle worked on my iphone so I looked at your source for moment.js which is cdnjs.cloudflare.com. I had been using a version that I had downloaded. I changed to using https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.13.0/moment.min.js and it solved my problem.

Answer (score 0):

Following code will give you all dates (inclusive):

```
var startDate = moment("2016-06-01");
var stopDate = moment("2016-09-29"):
var dateArr = [];
var interval = moment.twix(startDate, stopDate).iterate('days');
while (interval.hasNext()) {
  dateArr.push(interval.next().format('YYYY-MM-DD'))
};

console.log(dateArr);
```